# style.css and bootstrap.css gets mixed

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem which my style.css gets mixed with the bootstrap.css and the classes get mixed up my website doesent work

i dont know what to try

Comment: Need more information. Can you paste your file hierarchy, and paste the code responsible for importing `bootstrap.css`? Finally, say what class is getting overridden, what it is used for, and paste the relevant `style.css`.

Comment: ex: container I have a div with that class and when i added a carousel it changed the div too

Comment: Can you put this information in the question, and paste your CSS?